# About the consensus regarding the `input` tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There are several questions on our main site regarding the *format of input* needed for neural networks or other models.

When I search for tags, only the [`input-layer`](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-layer) tag is available. The description is

> Input layer is the first layer of any neural network and contains the
> input. Use this tag for asking questions related to this layer of the
> neural network.

Input layer can be treated as a part of the neural network. Input is what we pass to the network. There can be questions on input itself rather than the model.

So, I am thinking that the new tag `input` is needed for us. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: We already have the tag [tag:features] that should cover some of the cases that are related to inputs, but "feature" is more a synonym for "independent variable", while input would be like an observation/instance with can contain multiple features. The problem is that [tag:observation] may also refer to an observation in reinforcement learning, which may not be the same thing. Generally, I would avoid introducing tags that could be used for different purposes or inconsistently. When do you think people would use the tag "inputs"?

Comment: I mean, there are probably many cases, but I am just trying to understand if this tag could be used inconsistently or not.

Comment: [This](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/32721/what-are-the-types-of-inputs-used-for-rnn-in-literature-given-sentences) question can be an example to use input tag. @nbro